# How to efficiently edit the text in an EditText in Android

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I am new to java and android development and I am working on an application that takes input from the user through an EditText. However, sometimes the input data has some characters with an encoding that is different from what the app expects.

I have created a hashmap with all the possible mapping (about 460 elements) and whenever the user types in (or paste) something I use the afterTextChanged method to go through the text and swap the ones that matches the incorrect encoding with the correct ones that displays correctly.
My code works fine for small sized entry, however the longer it is the slower it gets because afterTextChanged will be called recursively after every swap I do. And when pasting a text that has about 30+ characters with incorrect encoding the application will crash.

here is my code:

```
public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
   substituteText(editable);
}

public CharSequence substituteText(Editable txt) {
   if (txt.length() == 0) {
      return txt;
   }

   for (int i = 0; i < txt.length(); i++) {
      char ch = txt.charAt(i);
      CharSequence ret = myHashMap.get(ch);
      if (ret != null) {
         txt.replace(i, i + 1, ret);
      }
   }

   return txt;
}
```

I thought about cloning "editable" to some, change it and then copy it back to the edittext editable variable so it will only see it as one change but I failed to do it since I couldn't find an easy way to clone it.

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use onTextChanged instead of afterTextChanged, you'll get passed the new character(s) the user typed and where they are, and you'd only need to check those.

Comment: But isn't the CharSequence that are passed by onTextChanged a read only? or you suggest the I use the EditText.setText to change it

Comment: Yes, but you can change the corresponding location within the edit text directly.  Or save the location data here and do the actual editing in afterTextChanged.

Comment: in the android documentation for "onTextChange" it says at the end: **It is an error to attempt to make changes to s from this callback.**. Why is that?

Comment: Yes, you can't modify s directly.  But you can modify the edit view that s comes from.